# How to output content use my custom way?

Tags: theming, blocks, javascript

For example, I have two site (A & B), A is built by drupal. On site B, I wanna display a list of news from site A. I choose to add such code to B's page

```
<script src='http://A/some_path'></script>
```

and in this script will use document.write to output content's on Site A

So how can I change A site's output, such as

```
<ul>
      <li>...
</ul>
```

to js output style

```
document.write('<ul>');
document.write('<li>...');
document.write('</ul>');
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Typically you would provide an API on your Drupal site (perhaps with the [Services module](https://drupal.org/project/services)) to allow consumption of the raw data, and use JS to build up the relevant markup on the receiving site. We can't write this for you (that's not something we do here, and plenty of it has nothing to do with Drupal), so I'd recommend having a look at the Services module, and coming back when you have more specific development questions

Comment: Actually, you could even go as simple as creating a View with an RSS feed, and consuming the RSS feed

Comment: I don't think this really is what you need, but if this is what you want, then simply create new display in your view on A, and use tpl files to wrap it with js commands.

Comment: Also `document.write` is a bad practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574098/is-document-write-actually-deprecated